# Зависает squashfs

Tags: archlinux, linux

Почему-то зависает squashfs. Останавливается на файле key-users.
Ввожу

```
mksquashfs / fs.squash
```

Что я делаю не так? Мне надо собрать дистрибутив на базе арча, чтобы размножить на более 20 ПК.

Answer (score 1):

вам надо загрузиться из другой системы ({live|rescue}-{cd|dvd|usb}, в котором есть программа `mksquashfs`), примонтировать раздел, образ которого вы хотите сделать, например, в `/mnt`, и тогда уже выполнять:

```
$ sudo mksquashfs /mnt путь.к.файлу.куда.будет.записан.образ
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант это собрать свой образ Арча на базе [Archiso](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archiso) используя как платформу x86_64 Арч.